# WPML Page with language specific links only

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I have a multi-lingual site using the WPML Worpress plugin. I need to create a Page with links to Posts that are just relevant to that language i.e. if you are on the English page only English post links are created....but I can't see to figure out the correct filtering method.

Here is the current code which displays all Post links...

```
<?php
foreach ($ps as $p) { ?>

    <a href="/<?=$p->post_name;?>" class="link-image-box">
        <div class="link-image-box__date">
            <?= date("d/m/Y",strtotime($p->post_date)) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="link-image-box__text">
            <?= $p->post_title ?>
        </div>
        <?=get_the_post_thumbnail($p->ID, null, ['class'=>'link-image-box__bg']);?>

    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: How are you getting the list of posts `$ps`?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, That's right